# Can you get the exact currently indexed key in types declaration?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, nested-object

I'm trying to create a relatively simple type that would enforce a nested object key reference to the outer level.

To clear things up a little, here's an example:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: {
     name: 'bar',
     ref: 'foo' // < this should reference the key of the parent
  }
}
```

This obviously wouldn't be an issue in a static object type, where we only need to check for `'foo'`, but I'm trying to make sure it's dynamic with generic type arguments.

I tried the following:

```js
type InnerObject<K> = {
   name: string,
   ref: K,
}

type OuterObject<T, K extends keyof T> = {
   [key in K]: InnerObject<K>
}
```

This works almost fine, enforcing type check on the union of the current keys:

[image]

Issue with this is, it also allows for passing the other object key to the `ref` property, when it explicitly shouldn't.

[image]

I've been thinking of somehow creating a third type generic and passing it to the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) utility type, i.e.

```
type InnerObject<T, K extends keyof T, CurrentKey> = {
   name: string,
   ref: Exclude<CurrentKey, K>
}
```

but issue is, I can't think of a way of passing the current key of the indexed object without writing an explicit reducer / map function on the outer object.

Is this feasible, or it's simply not possible in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript)?

---

Here's [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQN4CgoFQBmA9iQFxQDkcVANPoQEYIBOlVI9uAvrrqEhQAkgDtREVgHkmAKwgBjYAB4A0gD4oWPIVHIIlAM7BWAS1EBzBoVYQilVQz4Dw0KQFdgkmfKXKAKnRQqlAQcF6iACaGUADWECAkRFD+mtqMUADa8SBQ5sEAupRiEtJyiioavPwKJKLGUCRylB5eZb4q8MhoEEE5SbCIKOhpOBnEZJQ6hDN6SAbUAO4AFgheAG6S3DMztvbUpCTbhDzWzGxT47P6HCwAXsc7UHsch1RQAPQfUMDLpjGGZYkdyoSKiKjAKBgBCGQzjPg8IA) in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type like `Example` that you want to convert into this structure, you can do it like this:

```
type OuterObject<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: InnerObject<K>
}
```

The idea is that we are [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `InnerObject<K>` over *each* `K` in `keyof T`.

Importantly, the difference between this and what you wrote is that you were operating on the whole union `keyof T` and not each element in the union.  It's the difference between `{[X in Y]: F<X>}`, which evaluates to a possibly different type for each property, and `{[X in Y]: F<Y>}` which does not.

This produces the behavior you're looking for:

```
const obj: OuterObject<Example> = {
    foo: {
        name: 'whatever',
        ref: 'foo',
    },
    bar: {
        name: 'baz',
        ref: 'foo' // error!
    }
}
```

Does that work for you?

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQN4CgoFQBmA9iQFxQDkcVANPoQEYIBOlVI9uAvrrqEhQAkgDtREVgHkmAKwgBjYAB4A0gD4oWPISijkESgGdgrAJaiA5g12sIRSqoY8o-QdCkBXYJJnylygAqUBBwPqIAJkZQJHKKwJrajAQA2qpQFlAA1hAgJERQgQC6lGIS0nEBGq58uAokoiYxcpRePhX+KvDIaBCJOMnEZJQ6uoT6SIbUAO4AFgg+AG6S3GOEdg7UpCSrhDw2zGwjg7oTU1QsAF67axsc21RQAPRPIaysJKwAhIN8tUA)

Comment: Oooh that's smart. I didn't know you can create a mapped generic inside the actual key declaration. I was pretty close to it, basically just did the error of declaring it as a generic which resulted as the union of the two keys rather than the exact mapped key, as you correctly pointed out in your edit. Thank you! :-)